# Windows Explorer IShellFolderViewDual::SelectItem usage

Tags: c#, c++, ole, windows-shell, user32

I'm writing some code will automate selection of Window Explorer(explorer.exe) items. And I found two methods that might help:

```
HRESULT SelectItem(
  [in]  VARIANT *pvfi,
  [in]  int dwFlags
);
// from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd894079(v=vs.85).aspx

HRESULT SelectItemRelative(
  [in]  int iRelative
);
// from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774966(v=vs.85).aspx
```

I've tried `SelectItemRelative` and it works perfectly; next item in explorer is selected when I pass `1` as argument. The method is self-explanatory

Now, I don't quite get `SelectItem`, it takes a VARIANT and an int. According to MSDN, the int flag tells the method what kind of selection to make, and that's all, no explanation on what VARIANT is.

What should I pass for `VARIANT *pvfi`?

Answer (score 3):

`IShellFolderViewDual` is a *dual* to the (long gone IIRC) `IShellFolderView`. Some [vestigial documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/shellfolderview-selectitem) remains. Someone has been a fan of quantum physics, it seems.

The variant should carry a `VT_UNKNOWN` pointing to the `FolderItem` instance of the item you wish to change the selection of. Then, the selection flags are as follows:

- 0 (`SVSI_DESELECT`) deselect
- 1 (`SVSI_SELECT`) select
- 3 (`SVSI_EDIT`) put the item in edit mode
- 4 (`SVSI_DESELECTOTHERS`) deselect all bu the specified item
- 8 (`SVSI_ENSUREVISIBLE`) ensure that the item is visible in the view (scrollthe view)
- 16 (`SVSI_FOCUSED`) give the item the focus

Answer (score 2):

For **VARIANT** you may pass **LPCITEMIDLIST** of the item.